# List will not sort after appending variables to it (python 3)

Tags: list, sorting, append

I am working on another piece of code right now, however, I took a snippet out to show what happens when I try and sort a list after appending two variables to it. Any idea how I can fix this?

```
player1score = 10
player2score = 20
listwin = list()
listwin.append(player1score)
listwin.append(player2score)
sorted(listwin)
print(sorted(listwin))
```

Comment: This is explained in detail [in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the sorted method does not update your list. You need to use list.sort():

```
player1score = 10
player2score = 20
listwin = list()
listwin.append(player1score)
listwin.append(player2score)
listwin.sort()
print(listwin)
```

The difference between those methods is that sorted(listwin) returns a copy of listwin without changing it, while listwin.sort() changes listwin.